# discord.py - Command to modify roles that cannot be used if role has got permissions the user don't have

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a Discord BOT using the `discord.py-rewrite` library and I am facing a problem.
Indeed, I am making a command that can remove all permissions from roles we specify. But I want this command to be only usable by members with the `Manage Roles` permission, but members must also have all the permissions of the roles they are modifying.
For instance, a member **with** the `Manage Roles` permission but **without** the `View Audit Log` permission **WON'T BE ABLE** to execute this command on roles **with** the `View Audit Log` permission.
Anyone please now how I can manage this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the [`Permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Permissions) of the role and author, then confirm that the role permissions are a subset of the authors permissions:

```
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def remove_role(ctx, *, role: Role):
    if role.permissions <= ctx.author.permissions_in(ctx.message.channel):
        ...
    else:
        await ctx.send("You are missing permissions")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer Patrick Haugh, but it doesn't work :(

Comment: Do we need to loop every role permissions and see if the author has every of these permissions?

Comment: No, a `Permissions` object provides the subset functionality for us.  What do you mean when you say it doesn't work?  Are you seeing an error, is it allowing people without the correct permissions in, or is it restricting people who do have the correct permissions?

Comment: Well I've tested this on a server that I own but it doesn't let me use the command